# How to get SQL substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a column containing value like:

"AAAA\BBBBBBBB\CCC"  (A, B, C part length are not fixed.)

I need to trim out the \CCC part if it exists, and leave it alone if not exist.

For example:

AAA\BBBBBB\CCC  -> AAA\BBBBBB

AA\BBBB   -> AA\BBBB

AA  -> AA

**Sorry I am not clear enough, the A, B, C parts are not literally ABC, they could be any content.**

**Also \DDD\EEEE(etc.) should be removed as well**

Comment: You should find the third slash and truncate the text after that

Comment: So could you clarify : this is the part after the second '\' which must be replaced ? Or nothing to do with the number of '\' ?

Comment: Any chances there could be a \DDD segment? If so what you want to do with it?

Comment: @Crono Yes, it could be. All I want is to remove the parts after the first 2 parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there's certainly a way to do it in pure T-SQL, it might not be as clear as it could be.

You may want to consider using a [SQLCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-based user defined function (UDF) instead. With that you'll be able to benefit from the power and clarity of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) (or [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)) within Sql Server.

Just make it so that your function will receive your string as a param and return the output that you want as a scalar value. From then on you'll be able to use that function just like any other UDF you may already have. This way your code would be much easier to write (and read / maintain afterwards).

Your [sqlclr](/questions/tagged/sqlclr) function could be as easy to write as this (pseudo code):

```
public static string SpecialSubstring(string input)
{
    if (input == null) return null;

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var occurences = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++;)
    {
        var current = input[i];

        if (current == '\') occurences += 1;
        if (occurences >= 2) break;

        builder.Append(current)
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Then, from T-SQL:

```
SELECT
    [owningschema].SpecialSubstring('AAA\BBBBBB\CCC'), -- returns 'AAA\BBBBBB'
    [owningschema].SpecialSubstring('AA\BBBB'),, -- returns 'AA\BBBB'
    [owningschema].SpecialSubstring('AA') -- returns 'AA'
```

This page will give you pretty much all you need to get started:

[SQL Server Common Language Runtime Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 I have created SQL CLR functions in the past to expose the full functionality of the .Net framework RegEx engine since SQL itself is sorely lacking in such things.

Comment: @StevePettifer I did the exact same thing. When used correctly and for the right task, SQLCLR makes it much easier to do some operations. Sometimes it even outperforms T-SQL.

Comment: This. Especially if it is more than a one time query. (Although if it is more than a one time query, have a think about changing the underlying data structure.) A TSql version will be very expensive with all the string functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to remove the last part if there are two or more parts (separated by \)

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(32) = 'AAAA\BBBBBBBB\CCC'

SELECT
    LEN(@var) - LEN(REPLACE(@var, '\', '')) -- Number of occurences of the character \

    , CHARINDEX('\', @var) -- Position of the first occurence
    , LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@var)) -- Position of the last occurence

    , CASE WHEN LEN(@var) - LEN(REPLACE(@var, '\', '')) > 1 AND CHARINDEX('\', @var) !=  LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@var))
        THEN SUBSTRING(@var, 1, LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@var)))
        ELSE @var
    END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`PATINDEX`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to find out if the field has 3 (or more) parts, and then some string manipulation to chop off the last part:

```
select case 
       when PATINDEX(field, '%\%\%') > 0 then 
           /* Chop off last part */
           LEFT(field, len(field) - charindex('\', reverse(field)))
       else
           field
       end case as choppedfield
  from my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would accomplish this task:

```
declare @temp varchar(50), @temp2 varchar(15), @temp3 varchar(15)
set @temp = 'aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd'

IF (SELECT LEFT(@temp,CHARINDEX('\',@temp, CHARINDEX('\',@temp,0)+1))) != ''
    BEGIN
      SELECT LEFT(LEFT(@temp,CHARINDEX('\',@temp, CHARINDEX('\',@temp,0)+1)),LEN(LEFT(@temp,CHARINDEX('\',@temp, CHARINDEX('\',@temp,0)+1)))-1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
      select @temp
    END
```

Paste this into a query window and give it a shot with different `@temp` values.  It does a quick check to see if two `'\'`s exist, and trims it to the character place before the second `'\'`.  If less than two `'\'`s exist, it will just return the value itself.