# How to do substring in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to do a Sub String in SQL Server for following string :

`POINT (-71.237934 42.366352)`, I want only `-71.237934` after doing the sub string

Comment: With the `Substring` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get SQL substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014168/how-to-get-sql-substring)

Comment: how to do it in SQL server

Comment: Have you looked at [SUBSTRING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing some sort of work with spatial data. Consider the following:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT (-71.237934 42.366352)', 4326);
SELECT @g.Long
```

Comment: if there is a multi point like this MULTIPOINT ((-117.192682 34.499711), (-117.19537100010334 34.48850100011844)) ,how to get longitude value for this point??

Comment: That's really a new question in and of itself. We can do it, but in the comments to an answer for another question isn't really the place. Feel free to pose it as a new question and I (or someone else) will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [SUBSTRING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) 
and [CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)function

```
select substring('-71.237934 42.366352',0,
            charindex(' ','-71.237934 42.366352')
                )
```